# Intent is not open up when login is successful

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having problem that my intent won't open up after a successful login. it shows that my app has stopped working. I can't figure out why?

```
// check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
if(password.equals(storedPassword))
{
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    dialog.dismiss();
    **Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), FirstInterface.class);
    startActivity(i); // HERE IS THE INTENT CODING
} else {
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,
                   "User Name or Password does not match", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

What should I insert in my FirstInterface.class?

public class FirstInterface extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: post logcat error and make sure you have insert `FirstInterface` in your manifest as activity

Comment: I already inserted the FirstInterface as activuty in manifestt

Comment: why double star before `Intent`  ????

Comment: Maybe you have not included your FirstInterface activity in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure FirstInterface appears in your manifest likes this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FirstInterface"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

And use your activity context to start the new activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent (HomeActivity.this, FirstInterface.class);
startActivity(i);
```